# Can't update the height of an element in React

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I have an accordion with content (referred to as `children`).
When I open and close it all is well

But if the content inside changes its size, then nothing happens.

How can I update the height of the wrapper when the height changes inside the content?

The problem is that I need it for animation.

Here is some sample code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-breeze-96c1q?file=/src/Accordion.js